# image link not working if i don't open the image's link first

Tags: html

I have my images as links, I put them in the '*img*' tag in the '*source="https://i.imgur.com/ABCDEF..."*' space. My issue is, that if I don't open each link first, they don't load.

I don't really know what to try, the way I wrote the code works, only that i have to open each link first.

Links are in a JSON structure in github, I'm putting that info in my html via javascript

```html
<ul id="galleryUl">
  <h1 class="tracking-in-expand-fwd" id="h1Name">ANGELA &amp; VALENTINA</h1>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZOHGX1Z.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AWOW84K.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xXZYJjF.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mQhqGIG.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PfzJb37.jpg">
</ul>
```

It works here, but not in my page

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWEz.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Errors 401 and 403 are authorization errors, and usually it means that the content is stored in an area that the user needs to be logged into/ that they have no access to. From the path shown in the screenshot, however, it looks as though the images are being called incorrectly from the local host. If the `https://` part of the url is missing in your code that creates the image url, correct that first and try again, as without it. [Otherwise the code is expecting the images to be stored on your local machine.]

Hope this helps